# How to get correct indentation for the closing parenthesis in cperl-mode?

Tags: indentation, perl

I have problems with correct alignment of the closing parenthesis in `cperl-mode`. For example consider the following Perl code:

```perl
my $a = func1(
    Module::test()
  );

my $b = func2(
    test()
);

my $c = func3(
    Module::test(),
);
```

We see that the closing parenthesis is not correctly indented for `func1`, but for `func2` and `func3` it is correct.

In `cperl-mode-hook` I have

```el
(setq cperl-indent-level 4)
(setq cperl-indent-parens-as-block t)
(setq cperl-close-paren-offset -4)
```

What is the reason for this behavior, and how can I get correct indentation for the closing parenthesis also for `func1`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I usually have a keybinding for `perltidy`.

Comment: I don't do the perl, but I've met similar issue in Java/C++.
See http://blog.binchen.org/posts/ccjava-code-indentation-in-emacs.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this behavior is related to the newest version of `cperl-mode`. I am using Emacs 24.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, and the `cperl-mode` that came with the installation (`/opt/emacs24.4/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/progmodes/cperl-mode.el.gz`) is version 6.1 of `cperl-mode`.

I then tried to install `cperl-mode` from ELPA using Emacs 24.4 package manager (`list-packages`), and it turned out that it gave me version 5.23 of `cperl-mode` which also indented the closing parenthesis correctly..